# I am getting an error: "Cannot apply attribute class 'ICommand' because it is abstract"

Tags: c#, maui

[This is the code which I have used and I installed 8.0.0 version of MVVM package. I tried it with another version too](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IoFwQ.png)

I tried to resolve the issue by changing the package to current version but the same error is triggered again can you please help me to sort it

Comment: Post the code *as text* in the question itself. You probably referenced the wrong class. Did you use Intellisense to fix an error when you added `[Command....]` to a class? `Version 8 of MVVM package` doesn't explain anything - MVVM is a pattern and a *lot* of libraries implement it. More than 1 have "MVVM" in their name so we can't guess which one you may be using

Answer (score 1):

Please change the `[ICommand]` to the `[RelayCommand]`. Such as:

```
 [RelayCommand]
 void Add()
 {
 
 }
```

There is no `[ICommand]` attribute in the Community Toolkits MVVM package but a `[RelayCommand]` attribute.

Comment: is it work for delete too

Comment: Yes, the `[RelayCommand]` will convert the method to a Command can you can bind it in the xaml such as `{binding AddCommand}`, `{binding DeleteCommand}`. @srikanth